# Gradle build with Java 8

Tags: java, gradle, java-8

I'm trying to build Java 8 project with Gradle 1.6, but I'm stuck on this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':ejb:compileJava'
invalid target release: 1.8
```

JAVA_HOME is set as "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0", and build.gradle contains these lines:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK8 install directory?

Comment: Have you tried `"1.8"` instead of `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`?

Comment: @fge yes, and it fails with same error

Comment: I just noticed that typing "java -version" prints out 1.7.0_25. So there must be something wrong with my java_home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer. I replaced JAVA_HOME

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
```

with

```
D:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.8.0
```

and build succeeded.

Comment: Was your filesystem FAT32? Can't believe that I am seeing "Progra~1" in 2013.

Comment: My filesystem is ntfs

Comment: @perak I'm using this "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45" Or even this "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45" in JAVA_HOME, in both User variables and System variable in Environment Variables, But problem is still exist!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. The JAVA_HOME is set to  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31 but still getting the error . Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found picking wrong JAVA_HOME path value. After updating correct path, it's working for me. No need to do any change.