# invalid source release: 1.8 while Gradle build

Tags: java, windows, gradle, java-8

I have the following line in my `build.gradle`

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

And when I compile it, the following error occurs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> invalid source release: 1.8
```

Setting JAVA_HOME to short filename didn't help.

How to build with Gradle under Java 8 under Windows?

**UPDATE**

```
C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

C:\>dir %JAVA_HOME%
COPYRIGHT  README.html                         THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt  db       javafx-src.zip  lib      src.zip
LICENSE    THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt  bin                          include  jre             release
```

Comment: It occurs under console or when you work with IDE?

Comment: Can you share the content of your `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Can you try the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841589/gradle-build-with-java-8

Comment: @Opal you are right, it appear under IDE only; I was thinking running goal from under IDE is equivalent to run goal from command line.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878045/errorjava-invalid-source-release-8-in-intellij-what-does-it-mean